# Gnuplot repeats colors in rowstack histograms

Tags: colors, gnuplot

I am currently plotting some data using gnuplot with rowstacked histograms.
The problem is, that the colors start to repeat after 9 different colors have been chosen. One can see this also happening in the official gnuplot examples (see http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/histograms.html - Example 4 & 5)

Is there any way to tell gnuplot to use more different colors?

Answer (score 4):

There is no fully automated way to do this, but you can define as many line styles as you want with `set style line ...` and then use them. Here, I just use a simple iteration to define several colors:

```
do for [i=1:20] {
    set style line i linecolor rgb hsv2rgb(0.05*(i-1), 1, 1)
}
set style data histograms
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.75
plot for [i=1:20] 'mydata.dat' u 2 ls i t 'ls '.i
```

The data file contains just the values

```
1 0.1
2 0.2
3 0.3
```

Note, that the `hsv2rgb` function is defined only since 5.0. For earlier version you can use the following user-defined function to get the same functionality:

```
rgb2int(r,g,b) = int(255*r)*2**16 + int(255*g)*2**8 + int(255*b)
hsv2rgb(h,s,v) = (s == 0 ? rgb2int(v,v,v) : (HSV_h = h*6.0, HSV_i = int(floor(HSV_h)), HSV_f = HSV_h - HSV_i, HSV_p = v*(1.0 - s), HSV_q = v*(1.0-s*HSV_f), HSV_t = v*(1.0-s*(1.0-HSV_f)), (HSV_i%6 == 0 ? rgb2int(v,HSV_t,HSV_p) : (HSV_i%6 == 1 ? rgb2int(HSV_q,v,HSV_p) : (HSV_i%6 == 2 ? rgb2int(HSV_p,v,HSV_t) : (HSV_i%6 == 3 ? rgb2int(HSV_p,HSV_q,v) : (HSV_i%6 == 4 ? rgb2int(HSV_t,HSV_p,v) : rgb2int(v,HSV_p,HSV_q))))))))
```

To make it easier, you could put this code into a configuration file, or a third script `hsv2rgb.gp` and include it with `load 'hsv2rgb.gp'` before using the function.

Output with 4.6.3 is:

[image]

Comment: hsv2rgb throws undefined function error and I could not apply the patch that solves this problem. Can you please show a version of this code without hsv2rgb? I am using Gnuplot version 4.6 patchlevel 3.

Comment: @Jey Ups, hadn't noticed that `hsv2rgb` is available in 5.0 only. See my update for a user-defined function with (hopefully) the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution for an ordinary histogram style "set style data histograms", and I am not getting what I am expecting. I understand the OP's question is about rowstacked. Is this solution only applicable to rowstacked histograms? I also have only two columns in my data file.

Comment: In principle, the coloring should work for any kind of diagram. My example is a bit special: Instead of having a data file with twenty columns, I use one with only two columns but resuse the second column twenty times. I included the output I get with the above solution. If in your case it doesn't work you might ask a new question and provide the code and the data.

Comment: Here is the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633894/color-repetition-when-using-boxes-in-gnuplot/.  I am open to a solution using histograms too. I initially tried your solution, and when I failed, I switched to 'boxes', but still not achieving the effect.

Answer (score 3):

There is something a little more automated than Christoph's answer. You can use a color palette:

```
set palette rgb 7,5,15
unset colorbox
plot 'immigration.dat' using 2:xtic(1) title columnheader(2), \
     for [i=3:22] '' using i lt palette frac i/22. title columnheader(i)
```

The trick is, to define `frac` based on the loop counter `i`. Be sure to devide by a `float` (in this case `22.` to match the example) to get the right fractions of the color palette.
Or, for example 4:

```
plot 'immigration.dat' using (100.*$2/$24):xtic(1) t column(2), \       
     for [i=3:23] '' using (100.*column(i)/column(24)) lt palette frac i/23.\
     title column(i)
```

Now, you only have to decide on a suitable color palette.