# Is it possible to use do loop inside multiplot in gnuplot?

Tags: loops, colors, gnuplot

I need to create a figure with multiple subplots whereas in each subplot I need to plot multiple lines. Each line has to have a different color. (if every 30-40 lines the colors are iterated its ok for my purpose).

For example: ( I want 8 subplots)

```
set multiplot layout 2, 4
```

for the first subplot I can do the following

```
plot for [i=2:101] 'mydata.txt' u 1:i w line notitle lw 2
```

which will plot 100 lines inside the first subplot

```
plot for [i=1022:201] 'mydata.txt' u 1:i w line notitle lw 2
```

which adds another set of lines in the second panel etc.

The problem with this solution is that each separate line within the subplot gets not only a different color but also a different line style, some are solids some are dashed and each with different dash pattern etc.
**Is there any way to use a unique line style e.g. all continuous lines and have different colors?**

In the past I had found the following workaround, which works in the case of a single plot

```
rgb(r,g,b) = 65536 * int(r) + 256 * int(g) + int(b)
set multiplot

do for [i=2:201] { 
   rr = 255*rand(0)
   gg = 255*rand(0)
   bb = 255*rand(0)
   plot 'moredata.inp' u 1:i:(rgb(rr,gg,bb)) w line notitle lt 1 lc rgb variable lw 2
}
```

However I cannot replace the "plot for [i=2:101]" with the do loop because the result is one line per subplot.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use only solid lines, use

```
set termoption solid
```

In order to iterate over line colors, you can use `lc variable` (without the `rgb`!). In that case the last column is used as `linetype` index. If you want other colors of the linetypes you can use `set linetype ...`. If you use `set style increment user`, the index refers to `linestyles`.

Or you can use `lc palette` and define an appropriate palette, see e.g. [Gnuplot repeats colors in rowstack histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18149239/2604213). I think this might be the best option, because you need a lot of colors:

```
set palette model HSV defined ( 0 0 1 1, 1 1 1 1 ) # rainbow palette
plot for [i=2:101] 'mydata.txt' u 1:i lc palette frac (i/101.0) w line notitle
```

Comment: Than you the set termoption solid was the key issue!. To make the above line working I changed it as ...lc palette frac (i/101.0)...

Comment: @giorgk Right, I corrected the answer, thank you. I got confused with this and all `variable` options.

Comment: Thank you!! 
The "set termoption solid" was the key. To make the above line working I had to change it as ...lc palette frac (i/101.0)...
However at the end I found the default colors better than any of the palettes so I didnt use the lc options.