# gnuplot - linecolour: do not wrap around

Tags: plot, colors, gnuplot

**UPDATE**

So apparently, the order of options *does* matter. Wasn't aware of that. Still,

```
rowi=1
rowf=7
colour=0
plot for [i=0:rowf-rowi+3] filename.'.csv' u ($0+i):2:3:(colour=colour+1):xtic(1) every ::i+1::i+1 w errorbars pt 7 lc var notitle
```

will start re-using colour after the eight entry where I want a different colour for each of the 10 points plotted.

How do I do that?

Comment: It may be helpful if you mention what you're trying to do

Comment: Try putting the 'notitle' clause at the end, i.e. after "lc var".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gnuplot, the `lc` (`linecolor`) and `pt` (`pointtype`) parameters belong to the `w` (`with`) clause (see `help plot with`), so putting `notitle` between `pt 7` and `lc var` doesn't work. If you move the `notitle` clause to the end of the plot command line, this will fix the error you are getting. Like this:

```
plot for [i=0:rowf-rowi+3] filename.'.csv' u ($0+i):2:3:xtic(1) every ::i+1::i+1 w errorbars pt 7 lc var notitle
```

Without lc var, by default the colours will eventually repeat but you can set the palette to anything you like. See: [Gnuplot repeats colors in rowstack histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147334/gnuplot-repeats-colors-in-rowstack-histograms)